# Does anyone know of a SwiftUI compiler?

Tags: web-browser, gui, compiler, swift

I do not want something big to download, like Xcode, but I want an online SwiftUI compiler that I can open from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a website; AFAIK, SwiftUI is (unlike Swift itself) not open source, so if Apple doesn't provide a website for it, there is likely to be none.

According to [this blog post](https://www.objc.io/blog/2020/05/19/swiftui-without-an-xcodeproj/), it *is* possible to run a SwiftUI app directly from the command line, with only the Xcode Command Line Tools (installable with the command `xcode-select –install`), not the full package. That might help?